# Data Frame, panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to extract data from a single city in a dataset that contains data from different cities in the same column.

```
| City     | Temp     |
| -------- | -------- |
| New York | Warm     |
| Boston   | Cold     |
I New York I Warm     I
I Texas    I Cold     I
```

When i run my code it doesnt include any data, just the header.

Tried this Code

```
manhattan_df = complaints_df[complaints_df.Borough == "MANHATTAN"].loc[:, ['Complaint Type', 'Borough']]

manhattan_df
```

But as said, only displays header.

Comment: Your example table columns don't seem to match your code snippet. Would you be able to create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,3,4,], b=[5,6,7,8], c=[1,2,3,4]))
sub_df = df.query(f'a == 1').loc[:,['b','c']]
sub_df
```